# Can an AWS S3 bucket policy be used to restrict different access types to different users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an AWS S3 bucket, let's call it 'mybucket', and a bunch of AWS IAM users, one of which, let's say 'alice', should be able to do anything to 'mybucket', while other AWS IAM users should just be able to list contents and get objects in 'mybucket'.

I've set up a bucket policy like:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Allow 'alice' user complete access.",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:user/alice"
      },
      "Action": [
        "s3:*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket",
        "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Allow all other users read access",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:root"
      },
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket",
        "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

With this policy, I can still write to 'mybucket'.  I even removed the second statement object, and get the same results.

Is this the correct approach to achieving what I want to achieve?  If so, what is the problem with my bucket policy?  If not, what approach should I pursue?

Many thanks!

Comment: What user are you? Root? Or another named user like `arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:user/allen`?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon S3 bucket policies are generally used to grant access to *everybody* (eg public users).

If you wish to grant specific permissions to particular IAM Users, then it is better to **add the policy directly to the IAM User or Group**.

For example, add this policy to the `alice` IAM User to allow her to run any API command on both the bucket and the objects within the bucket:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

You'll notice that there is no `Principal` field, because it automatically applies to the User on whom this policy is placed.

When Amazon S3 evaluates permissions, it looks at both the Bucket Policy and any policies associated with the User. Either can grant access.